# Zeta function Re(s)=1

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Here I am considering the original zeta function (not the extended one)$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$
When Re(s)>1, the Zeta function converges, and if Re(s)<1 it diverges.

Here is my question. What happens when Re(s)=1?

I know it diverges when s=1, but does it converge otherwise?

Comment: No, the series diverges whenever $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$. That's not totally easy to prove, though.

Comment: [Relevant MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84097/divergence-of-dirichlet-series)